# What are the Set of values of $m$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

### **[Question :-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcRRe.jpg)**

> $A(-4, 0)$ and $B(4, 0)$ are two fixed points on argrand plane then the set of values of $m$ for which two another points $C$ and $D$ in argrand plane satisfying $\Im(Z) = m\Re(Z) + 8$ are such that $$\left| \arg\left(AC\over BC\right) \right| = \left| \arg\left(AD\over BD\right) \right| = {\pi \over 2}$$

---

$C$ and $D$ will be lying in each half part of the circle $$x^2 - y^2 -2x=0$$

And $$y = mx+8$$

but now how to proceed .

can anybody please help me in this

Comment: Please try learn MathJax typesetting and avoid images of text and formula.

Comment: @mathreadler can you help me in this .

Comment: Is AC the product of A and C? Or does it represent something else?